# jQuery scroll div when mouse not over it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs that are side by side which when the page loads are set to the window height.  Because the div on the right has lots of text in I've added a `overflow-y: scroll` to it.

What I want to achieve is for the div on the right to scroll even when you are hovering over the div on the left.  Is this possible with jQuery?

I know I could do it without jQuery if I do some clever things in CSS where I absolute the right div but ideally I just want to do it using JS.

I've set up an example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvrvcLsq/3/)

```
<section id="scroll-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 left"></div>
        <div class="col-6 right">
            <p>Lots of text will be in here</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```css
#scroll-block {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scroll-block .left {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x600');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#scroll-block .right {
  padding: 10% 8%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#scroll-block .row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scroll-block .left, #scroll-block .right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things, if you want to scroll through one piece of content while keeping the other piece in place, you should arrange the pieces so that one is position: fixed; and placed on top of the other content. A more effective way to display at 100% the height of the viewport is height:100vh;. If you layout the page in this manner you will scroll anywhere on the page and the layout will remain consistent. Here is an example:

```
<style>
html, body{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
div.left {
   background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x600');
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 38%;
   position: fixed;
   height: 100vh;
}
div.right {
   float: right;
   width: calc(62% - 20px);
   padding: 10px;
}
</style>

<body>
   <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="right">
      <p>Large amounts of content. Images, text, what have you.</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. You could set the height of the class="right" to 100vh and overflow: auto; if you wanted it to scroll with an overflow, but you would be stuck with the same scrolling issue you have now.